# How to switch main memory power states

Tags: c, linux, memory, operating-system, kernel

I am working a project that require to switch memory power states by software. Example, when a RAM DIM is not in use, I need to be able to set it for stand-by power.

I know that memory system has these many states: idle, stand-by, self-refresh, precharge, active, read, and write. From those states, I need to be able by the OS to dynamically switch from one to the other. I would prefer to work on the linux OS.

Does any one has an idea how to manipulate those states from the operating system?

Comment: This is a very low-level hardware-specific (memory controller) subject. VTC as too broad.

Comment: You need to use Assembly.

Comment: Seems the linux kernel may already support what you're talking about. https://lwn.net/Articles/565371/

Comment: The solution presented is not exactly what I was looking for due to it is relaying on the memory controller to set different power states after a certain threshold is met. Therefore, we don't have control about the power stats of the memory, just how the memory allocation is done which in theory is going to free some DIMs which as a result is going to met the threshold set by the controller. Any how, we can not manually set the memory states when is need it by the OS.